# tx.gasprice always returns "1"

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to know the cost of the deployment transaction of my contract. I read the documentation, and there says that I have to use tx.gasprice. I made some test in Remix, in order to prove this method, but it always returns a value of "1" and I don't think this value is gonna be the same every time.

Am I wrong? There is another way to know this value inside the contract?

Comment: What is the `tx` variable?

Answer (score 1):

i test `tx.gasprice` is ok in remix, do you use it like this:

```
function test() constant returns (uint){
        return tx.gasprice;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The OP seems to be confusing gas spent with gas price.

Answer (score 0):

To get the amount of gas spent on a transaction, the transaction needs to be mined. You can then look it up using the `txHash`:

```
var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b');
console.log(receipt);
{
  "transactionHash": "0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockHash": "0xef95f2f1ed3ca60b048b4bf67cde2195961e0bba6f70bcbea9a2c4e133e34b46",
  "blockNumber": 3,
  "contractAddress": "0xa94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 314159,
  "gasUsed": 30234,
  "logs": [{
         // logs as returned by getFilterLogs, etc.
     }, ...]
}
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt)